# get the number of rows - mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying this code but i want to know what is the number of results of this query. If do the same query in mysql console I get 4 results, but with this code I get 0 rows. 
What is the correct way to get the number of rows ?

```
 function check_oferta_existe($db, $id, $id_oferta) {
            $sql = $db -> prepare("
            SELECT COUNT(offer)
            FROM offer
            WHERE company_users_id_user1 = ? AND offer = ? AND state = 0
            ");

            $sql -> bind_param('is', $id, $oferta);
            $sql -> execute();
            $sql -> fetch();
            $sql->store_result();
            $rows = $sql->num_rows;

            var_dump($rows); // 0, should be 4
            if ($rows == 1) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            };
        }
```

Comment: This is not a problem with `num_rows` as it is indeed a property. Check your SQL statement. It's likely failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two errors in your code. When you do this statement:

```
$sql -> bind_param('is', $id, $oferta);
```

you use `$oferta` but seems (looking at the function parameters) that the var should be `$id_oferta`.

Moreover, after the closing bracket of your `else` you have a semicolon which should not be there.

Comment: Don't diss the lucky semicolon :)

Comment: i am doing a count, so obviously the number of rows is always the same, one.

Comment: However, you are correct too. I forgot to change these parameters.

Answer (score 3):

`$sql->fetch()` is not a function - try `$sql->fetch_all()`.

That should fetch all the rows for you, and then the `$sql->num_rows` variable should be correct.